# Swift Not Pulling Data from Firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I have a bunch of objects within Firestore in this format. It worked perfectly when I didn't include the arrays within the objects but now it doesn't seem to be loading at all.

Here is the database: [image: :]

Here is the object:

```
struct BuildingNew: Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable{
    var id : String = UUID().uuidString
    var ml : String
    var name : String
    var address : String
    var description : String
    var phone : String
    var website : String
    var imageURL: String
    var historicalRelevance : String
    var images : [String]
    var tags : [String]
}
```

Finally, here is the view model:

```
class BuildingViewModelNew: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var buildings = [BuildingNew]()
    
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func fetchData(){
        db.collection("buildings_new").addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let documents = querySnapshot?.documents else {
                print ("No buildings found")
                return
            }
            self.buildings = documents.map { (queryDocumentSnapshot) -> BuildingNew in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                 
                let ml = data["ID"] as? String ?? ""
                let name = data["Name"] as? String ?? ""
                let address = data["Address"] as? String ?? ""
                let description = data["Description"] as? String ?? ""
                let phone = data["Phone"] as? String ?? ""
                let website = data["Website"] as? String ?? ""
                let imageURL = data["current_image"] as? String ?? ""
                let historicalRelevance = data["historicalRelevance"] as? String ?? ""
                let images = data["images"] as? [String] ?? [""]
                let tags = data["tags"] as? [String] ?? [""]

                return BuildingNew(ml: ml, name: name, address: address, description: description, phone: phone, website: website, imageURL: imageURL, historicalRelevance: historicalRelevance,images: images, tags: tags)
        }
    }
}
}
```

It's fetching the data in SwiftUI using the .OnAppear function but ever since the arrays were added - it hasn't worked. I've tried using **Array < String > rather than [String]** but have had no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not because of the arrays, it's because your field names don't match. In your code, some field names are uppercased:

```
let ml = data["ID"] as? String ?? ""
let name = data["Name"] as? String ?? ""
...
```

However, in your database they are lowercased:

```
id:   "MLid"
name: "daves diner"
```

Therefore, change the following to lowercase:

```
let ml = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
let address = data["address"] as? String ?? ""
let description = data["description"] as? String ?? ""
let phone = data["phone"] as? String ?? ""
let website = data["website"] as? String ?? ""
```